# Why broadcasting error with same array shapes

Tags: python, opencv

```
img1 = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread('rsz_katrina.jpg')

img1+img2
```

```
ValueError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-475bd2d47c0f> in <module>()
      2 img2 = cv2.imread('rsz_katrina.jpg')
      3 
----> 4 img1+img2

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (225,225,3) (255,255,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a close look at the dimensions in your error message: The sizes are different (225 and 255).